# variable value from a php file - Smarty multilingual

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, multilingual

I have a site (using Smarty template) which is multilingual. All the languages are in a different lang.ini file. 
E.g.: 
lang/eng/lang.ini: (In English)

```
WELCOME = "Welcome"
```

lang/hun/lang.ini: (In Hungarian)

```
WELCOME = "Üdvözöllek"
```

Then in the index.php:

```
... 
$error=array(); 
if($condition!=$condition2) 
{ 
     $error1 = "This is an error msg"; 
     array_push($error, $error1); 
} 
... 
$this->tpl->assign('error', $error); 
$lang_file=parse_ini_file("lang/". $_SESSION["lang_folder"] ."/lang.ini",true); 
$this->tpl->assignByref("lang",$lang_file); 
$this->tpl->display('index.tpl');
```

Finally in the index.tpl:

```
... 
{$lang.WELCOME} 
<br /> 
{if isset($error) && $error ne "" } 
   {foreach $error as $error_list} 
      {$error_list} 
   {/foreach} 
{/if} 
...
```

Now the Welcome can appear in different languages (the path stored in session). 
But the $error appears only one language, only print out it's value. 
How can I print it out depending which language is selected? Where should I add value to the $error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When detecting the error, rather than pushing the English string into your array, push the code you want to retrieve from your INI file:

```
if($condition!=$condition2) 
{ 
    array_push($error, 'ERROR_ONE'); 
}
```

Then in Smarty, use that as a key in your `$lang` array using normal array access syntax:

```
{foreach $error as $error_code} 
    {$lang[$error_code]} 
{/foreach}
```